# FInd the width of contenView in a UITableViewCell in case of iPad

Tags: ipad, uitableview, width

On iPAD when you create new UITableViewCell the contentView width set for 320. Is there a way to get the right width? I can't use the width of the current view as the table cells do not span the entire width of the view. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGFloat viewWidth = self.contentView.frame.size.width;
```

This gives the right width for `contentView`. If `[super layoutSubviews]` is not called initially then the `contentView` frame is not set correctly.

Comment: Presumably this is in a custom tableview cell.

Answer (score 5):

I've solved this issue using:

```
cell.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.origin.x,
                                        cell.contentView.frame.origin.y,
                                        self.tableView.frame.size.width,
                                        cell.contentView.frame.size.height);
```